# cual es el limite de un id, en base de datos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo una base de datos en `Postgres` que ya va funcionando una semana y la cantidad de datos ingresados son de 3788, este numero refleja el `id` de mi tabla, ademas me informan que esta cantidad es similinar por semana.

Creo el `id` de la siguiente forma:

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('memoria_id_seq'),
```

Entonces, lo que me preocupa y queria saber es:

> **¿Cual es el limite de este id?
>
>   ¿Me conviene cambiar de base de datos para ampliar este id?
>
>   ¿O tal vez solo tendria que cambiar de tipo de dato?¿Cual seria este tipo de dato?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El campo al ser de tipo `INT`; posee las siguientes características

> int (integer): Rango es de -2,000,000,000 a 2,000,000,000 mas o menos.

Aunque perfectamente puedes ocupar `BIGINT`

> bigint (big integer): calculando sería aprox. `2^64`

lo que si te debe ocupar en cualquier gestor es la calidad y lógica de tus queries para extraer datos

A continuación puedes ver las tablas con los tipos de datos tanto en PostgreSQL como en MySQL para tener una idea clara

**Mira esta tabla y checa la fuente (PostgreSQL)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Tipos de datos](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Lo que si debes revisar conforme crezca tu sistema, son: ancho de banda de la que dispone el servidor web, memoria RAM, calidad de las consultas SQL, etc etc

**En la siguiente tabla te muestro las longitudes de los datos para MySQL para que compruebes que eso no depende del gestor de bases de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mil gracias, te todos modos creo que cambiare el tipo de dato de `int` a `bigint`, por si acaso.